# How to insert tab into the output to a file in Python?

Tags: python, windows

How do I insert a tab into the output to a file in Python?

For example,

```
  print >>outPutFile , c.lstrip()+"\t"+d.rstrip('\n')+"\t"+a+"\t"+b
```

Output:

```
  cfn79e739_1.lp  260175  79      739

  cfn100e1217_1.lp        288734  100     1217
```

The second line has no tab after 288734. Why?

The first line has no tab after cfn79e739_1.lp and 260175. Why?

I need to make each column at the same alignment.

Comment: There is a tab in your output (everything is aligned to 8th columns).

Comment: Unrelated notes: (1) The Python way of adding all these tabs would be `'\t'.join([c.lstrip(), d.rstrip(…),…])`.  (2) Your `d.rstrip('\n')` could probably be simplified (and made a bit more powerful) as `d.rstrip()`, which also strips whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

Work out the maximum width for each column, and then pad each value accordingly:

```
lines = [
    ['cfn79e739_1.lp', '260175', '79', '739'],
    ['cfn100e1217_1.lp', '285768', '100', '1217'],
    ['cfn200e11660_1.lp', '288734', '200', '11660'],
    ['cfn1500e145_1.lp', '218435', '1500', '145'],
    ]

def print_columns(lines, spacing=2):
    widths = [max(len(value) for value in column) + spacing
              for column in zip(*lines)]
    for line in lines:
        print(''.join('%-*s' % item for item in zip(widths, line)))

print_columns(lines)
```

Output:

```
cfn79e739_1.lp     260175  79    739    
cfn100e1217_1.lp   285768  100   1217   
cfn200e11660_1.lp  288734  200   11660  
cfn1500e145_1.lp   218435  1500  145
```

Comment: +1: very good solution.  Indeed, tabulations are not a solution to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. But that's not how tabs work. They move the cursor to the next column that is a multiple of eight. If you want perfectly tabular alignment then you should use string interpolation or formatting with a known size.

```
>>> print '%-20s %-4d' % ('foo', 42)
foo                  42  
>>> print '%-20s %-4d' % ('bar', 13)
bar                  13
```

Comment: No downvote, but tabs do not always "move the cursor to the next column by a multiple of 8" (you can for instance ask the `less` pager to put tabs at any multiple); this sentence should be qualified, at the very least.